# JSON response in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, firefox

I'm making a request in my JS and getting back a json response from the server just fine in Chrome and IE, but for some reason the response I get from firefox isn't working. It looks like it isn't being encoded with UTF-8, but I know that it is from the server and all of my files are as well. The response I get in FF looks like

```
incoming Text ��[�{�"�m�e�t�a�d...
```

(I cut of the vast majority of it, but there is that question mark in between every character). The console then says `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"`

My .ajax call is as follows:

```
var locationURL = "https://myData.com/Metadata.json";
$.support.cors = true;
var jsonData = $.ajax({

    url: locationURL,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
});
```

The response header I get back (from firebug) is:

```
Accept-Ranges:  bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...:   *
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 81950
Content-Type:   application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:   Mon, 10 Aug 2015 14:03:51 GMT
Etag:   "c80b2-1401e-51c80111c1d00"
HSID:   Q01-21C D=601
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:  Tue, 04 Aug 2015 18:00:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j
```

Again, in Chrome and IE the response I'm getting is perfectly valid JSON, without all those extra characters. I see in the console that chrome makes the request to the URL as I have it typed in, but in the firefox console it adds `?_=1439215432794` to the end of the URL, might this have something to do with it? How do I get it to not add that? I put a `#` at the end of the URL when saving it inside locationURL, but that didn't make a difference. I also tried Jquery's `getJSON` instead of `.ajax` but that also didn't help. Any help or direction would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the server is returning gzip encoded data and not marking it correctly. If so, that's a server configuration issue.

Comment: `?_=1439215432794` is a cache buster. It's nothing to worry about and it is  added by jQuery, not Firefox. Don't say cache: false if you don't want it.

Comment: @Quentin I see in the request header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`, so that could definitely be accurate. Where exactly would I address a service configuration issue?